# How change colors of top bar control panels?

Tags: themes, colors

[image: screenshoot]

How can I change colors of this box and box-keyboard-layout and calendar?

/* ubuntu 18.04 / gnome shell 3.28 */

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gnome Shell uses a different theme than your application windows and dialogs. You can change the theme of Gnome Shell in Gnome Tweaks, appearance tab, provided you have installed the [User Themes](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/19/user-themes/) extension first.

Once you installed that extension, the selection box next to "Shell" on the "Appearance" tab in Gnome Tweaks, will be active to set a Gnome Shell theme.